# Punctuation after the interjection "by heaven"

Tags: punctuation, commas, interjections, exclamation-mark

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exclamation marks in the middle of a sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25232/exclamation-marks-in-the-middle-of-a-sentence)

How would you punctuate the following phrase with "by heaven"? It was used by a cricket commentator.

> - By heaven that's a good stroke!
> - By heaven! That's a good stroke!
> - By heaven, that's a good stroke!

Answer (score 2):

It would normally only be written as a record of direct speech and not as part of a piece of continuous prose. Either of the two ways you have shown would serve the purpose.

Comment: *We are anxiously waiting for our last man to hit and by heaven, that's a good stroke!* The answer is good, nevertheless.

Comment: @Gorpik: What about comma between *and* and *by heaven*? Wrong? Optional? Needed?

Comment: @SF. _And_ doesn't occur in the original speech.

Comment: @BarrieEngland I was just trying to give an example where that would be written in continuous prose.

Comment: @SF I really don't know. I don't like commas after *and*, but I may very well be wrong on that.

Comment: @Gorpik: That wasn't the question the OP asked. If you have a question about commas after _and_, you may like to ask it as a separate question (although it may already have been asked).

Comment: Actually, this falls well within realm of "Punctuating by heaven interjection", it's just omitted in OP's example.

Comment: @SF. _And_ isn't a punctuation mark.

Comment: @BarrieEngland I know, that was just a comment about your direct speech reference. I was not trying to open additional questions.

Comment: @Barrie: Yes, but a comma that might or might not go between *and* and *by* is.