# Can you really start new sentences with a lower-case letter like this?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

From *The Hobbit*, first chapter:

> “Confusticate and bebother these dwarves!” he said aloud. “Why don’t they come and lend a hand?” Lo and behold! there stood Balin and Dwalin at the door of the kitchen, and Fili and Kili behind them, and before he could say *knife* they had whisked the trays and a couple of small tables into the parlour and set out everything afresh.

"Lo and behold! there stood..." should be "Lo and behold! There stood...", no?

> “Bless me!” said Thorin, “haven’t you got a map? and didn’t you hear our song? and haven’t we been talking about all this for hours?”

Shouldn't this be:

> “Bless me!” said Thorin, “haven’t you got a map? And didn’t you hear our song? And haven’t we been talking about all this for hours?”

?

Comment: He's not starting a new sentence. He's using an exclamation mark in the middle of a sentence: [see the answers to this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25232/exclamation-marks-in-the-middle-of-a-sentence). There is [a similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36821/using-a-question-mark-mid-sentence) about question marks mid-sentence.

Comment: @StuartF What I find frustrating about your comment is that I would never object to the examples the person gives in your linked-to question. Those examples he gives seem entirely natural to me. The ones I provide are completely different in nature to me.

Comment: We look to our classics to define our standards, so *Can you really start?* gets a yes. And *Shouldn't this be* capitalized also gets a yes. Probably best to use the lowercase only for shock value.

Comment: Google Books has many different contexts featuring the sequence [***lo and behold there stood***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22lo+and+behold+there+stood%22). Glancing at the first couple of dozen, the *only* one that capitalises ***There*** seems to be a [TEFL text](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/New_Voices_Coursebook_7/RQntDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22lo+and+behold+there+stood%22&pg=PA13&printsec=frontcover) authored by people with non-Anglophone looking names, who apparently ***arbitrarily*** "corrected"  Tolkien's usage as cited here.

Comment: (Imho, true Anglophones would know better than to take issue with *Tolkien's* orthography, of all writers! :)

Comment: Tolkien was a linguist and everything he did, including his punctuation, was done on purpose. So there isn't any _Shouldn't this be...?_ for a published best-selling author who was also an authority on language and writing. If you want bad examples, read a newspaper. If Tolkien didn't follow the rules you've been taught, the conclusion to draw is that you've been taught the wrong rules.